# Can I edit a class without removing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got different languages on my website. Every language has the same products with a different class name per product. so lets say we've got this:

```
<div id="post-2036" class="willy peter pieter don donkey">
  <div class="product1 productiana prodonnie">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product2 prengdenga prodnie">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product3 oestnak ifweuhiw">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product4 iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product5 iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 5</div>
</div>
```

This is the same for every language. As you can see every class has multiple classnames, and I only need the first classname to get the initials of the language that is currently active.

I got the language initials out of the url by using

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

now I only have to use the outcome of 'url' to be added to the product1, product2, product3 classnames etc.

So that eventually it will look like this (when the user is on the italian page for example):

```
<div id="post-2036" class="willy peter pieter don donkey">
  <div class="product1_it productiana prodonnie">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product2_it prengdenga prodnie">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product3_it oestnak ifweuhiw">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product4_it iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product5_it iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 5</div>
</div>
```

I hope I stated my question clearly enough, if not please let me know, thanks a lot!

Comment: To answer the question in your title, no. You'll need to remove the class then add the amended version. However, this seems like an XY question as there are lots of better ways of achieving a multi-language site than having to append/amend the classes of multiple elements. Why exactly do you need to amend these classes? At the very least you could just add `it` as a class to the parent `div` and use `product` as a generic class on the children.

Answer (score 3):

Follow below approach:-

1.Get class first.

2.Add url value to it.

3.Add this class back to the div

Working snippet:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var url = 'it';
 
 $('div#post-2036').find('div').each(function(){
     var class_array = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');// split classes to make it array
     class_array[0] = class_array[0]+'_'+url; // add lang value to first class
     $(this).removeClass().addClass(class_array.join(' ')); // now add the new class to div
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-2036" class="willy peter pieter don donkey">
  <div class="product1 productiana prodonnie">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product2 prengdenga prodnie">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product3 oestnak ifweuhiw">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product4 iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product5 iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your reply it worked! only one thing, what do you change the selector into when there are divs inside other divs within the div with the post id? In the current status it edits all the divs inside the selected one

Comment: @Ryan You use `.children()` instead of `find()`, still, this is exactly why shouldn't do this, even if you technically can. Use something what I suggested, as with that you will gain so many more benefits.

Comment: @Ryan  i am unable to get your question. can you please explain? Also if you are using post-id as an id attribute of any html element then it need to be presenet on only one element inside whole rendered html, not on two-three or more. `id` treated as unique selector in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest, and most preformant solution is to take the language variable you got from the url, and add it as a class on the `html` element.

With that you can then use that class, combined with e.g. the `product1` and do like this:

Script

```
(function (d,url) {
    d.classList.add(url);
})(document.documentElement,window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]);
```

HTML

```
<html class='it'>
```

CSS

```
.it .product1 {

}
```

---

Or using an attribute

Script

```
(function (d,url) {
    d.setAttribute('data-lang',url);
})(document.documentElement,window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]);
```

HTML

```
<html data-lang='it'>
```

CSS

```
[data-lang='it'] .product1 {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant make it just like that.

Better way to have one language one identification class.

```
<div id="post-2036" class="willy peter pieter don donkey">
  <div class="product1 english productiana prodonnie">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product2 english prengdenga prodnie">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product3 english oestnak ifweuhiw">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product4 english iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product5 english iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 5</div>
</div>
```

Than when you switch to other language remove english and add new class french.

More better way to put english language class just on one place in container for example.

Except your product can be on one page in more different languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.attr()` function of jQuery to change the class tag of the elements by hand.

Also you can use the `.find()` function to find elements with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can find 1st class add  something to class (in your case comes from url ) remove old class and add new class.

```js
var url = 'it';
$('#post-2036').find('div').each(function(index, element) {
  var cls = $(this).attr('class');
  var st = cls.split(' ');
  var firstClass = st[0];
  var newClass=st[0]=firstClass+'_'+url
  console.log(newClass);
  $(this).removeClass(firstClass).addClass(newClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post-2036" class="willy peter pieter don donkey">
  <div class="product1 productiana prodonnie">Product 1</div>
  <div class="product2 prengdenga prodnie">Product 2</div>
  <div class="product3 oestnak ifweuhiw">Product 3</div>
  <div class="product4 iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 4</div>
  <div class="product5 iuerghreiuh ruehreiuh ">Product 5</div>
</div>
```